# How to fetch mails from folder/sub folder other than INBOX?

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems, mumps

I have got the code to read the mail from my INBOX folder.
But, i am unable to read the mails from folders other than  INBOX.
Below is my code used for fetching mail only from my INBOX.

```
; display mail but don't delete from mailbox
testmail6 ;
new mailserver,status,err,mailMsg
set mailserver=##class(%Net.POP3).%New()
set mailserver.AttachDir="d:\attach\"  ; need terminating \
set mailserver.StoreAttachToFile=1
write !,"Calling Connect"
set status=mailserver.Connect("Server.com","user","password")
if $$$ISERR(status) do DecomposeStatus^%apiOBJ(status,.err) write !,err(err),! quit
write !,"Calling Fetch to retrieve the oldest message on the server."
set status=mailserver.Fetch(1,.mailMsg,0)
if $$$ISERR(status) do DecomposeStatus^%apiOBJ(status,.err) write !,err(err),! quit
write !,"from="_mailMsg.From
write !,"to="_mailMsg.Headers.GetAt("to")
write !,"date="_mailMsg.Date
write !,"subject="_mailMsg.Subject
write !,"messagesize="_mailMsg.MessageSize
do DumpMessage(mailMsg)
quit
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do it in any language, because POP3 does not support any folders at all, just list of all incomming messages. Such folders supports in IMAP, but Cache does not have any realizations of using it by default.
You can found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/intersystems-public-cache/imap/intersystems-public-cache/5HRQnw1pAyU/SZRhoMiLXLUJ) a guy who offer his IMAP adapter, it is may help you